# How to use cross domain in webview with android SDK 28?

Tags: android, webview

While developing Android App, I can use "**webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true)**" to do "**cross-domain**" in webview with "targetSdkVersion=26".

However, I change targetSdkVersion **from 26 to 28**, it can not to do "cross-domain" in webview.

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

In manifest, adding  Application label with

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

It work！